# requestPointerLock() issues on chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code :

```
$(function() {

document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);

function mouseUp(e) {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveCallback, false);
    document.exitPointerLock = document.exitPointerLock ||
                               document.mozExitPointerLock ||
                               document.webkitExitPointerLock;
    document.exitPointerLock();
}


function mouseDown(e) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCallback, false);
    ptrLock($('body')[0]);              
}


function ptrLock(c) {
    console.log("ptrLock");
    c.requestPointerLock =  c.requestPointerLock ||
                            c.mozRequestPointerLock ||
                            c.webkitRequestPointerLock;

    c.requestPointerLock();             
}


function moveCallback(e) {

    movementX = e.movementX ||
                e.mozMovementX          ||
                e.webkitMovementX       ||
                0,
    movementY = e.movementY ||
                e.mozMovementY      ||
                e.webkitMovementY   ||
                0;

    console.log(movementX + " " + movementY);

}

})
```

The goal is to lock the pointer on mouseDown, call moveCallback while moving the mouse and unlocking the pointer when mouseUp.

It is working fine expect that if I click the mouse a single time without moving it, moveCallBack will be called twice with some weird values under chrome (always 8 or -8 for movementY).

logs on chrome:

```
ptrLock
0 0
0 8
```

logs on firefox (working fine):

```
ptrLock
0 0
```

Comment: Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a32AJ/1/ . When I click and move, it displays mouse delta. Are you sure your mouse is actually not moving or twitching?

Comment: what happen if you click once fast and don't move ? does it display 0 0 or nothing ? It could be a bug with my mouse indeed, but why would the problem only occur on chrome and not firefox then ?

Comment: What you mean exactly by 'click once fast' ? Single clicking is instant process, is't it?

Comment: just a normal click without moving the mouse

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1uk6pv5yqiegs5/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-05-27%2012.52.35.png thats two clicks without movement, one and few seconds after another

Comment: I have the same thing when using firefox, but on chrome I have an addition "0 8" after each "0 0". I guess I'll just wait and see if anyone has the same problem, otherwise I'll just try on another computer or with a different mouse.

Comment: You can just add some special handling, like filtering first 50 ms of input events, or explicit filtering of first event.

Comment: I would prefer to first know the source of the problem before doing some tricks to go around it : p